# Does serverless solution with AWS Lambda and React.js performant?

Tags: reactjs, aws-lambda, server-side-rendering

I want to understand does AWS Lambda and React.js is performant solution for serverless Single Page Application with Server Side Rendering. Maybe someone has already used it on production and can share about how bad or good it's working.

Also, would be interesting how it's ease/hard to build and support SPA with routing and server side rendering based on AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is.

My team and I have built several ReactJS + Serverless + DB and so far it seems very responsive and scales nicely. Like any other app stack you will choose, the biggest bottlenecks turn out to be data fetching and manipulation such as joins in the DB etc. Obviously, architecting your app's data structure is key here because most of the delays we have experienced so far come from poor DB queries or missing indexes, etc.

A clean request which goes: DB query -> node6 lambda fetch -> send data through API gateway -> client side, will take around 300-400 millisecond. So, as long as you have a good data structure and solid code your SPA should be performant. The frontend of our apps are hosted with cloudfront - which is very solid and super fast.

We haven't even started performance optimization or adding layers of caching to boost performance, so I suspect soon you will see full apps built with this stack that are super efficient and load fast.

Note: the recent (April/May 2017) upgrade to node6 LTS was a big improvement in performance.

Comment: But did you use server side rendering(on lambda) or only client side rendering?

Comment: @SergeyShvager we use it to send json objects only at this time. We do all the rendering with React on the client side. Our current app does not need any server side rendering. To be honest though if it's only changing the format of the data from json to let's say HTML snippets and you are only manipulating text in memory - it should be minimal overhead, probably unnoticeable at all.